# Защита JavaScript кода от атак

Tags: javascript, безопасность, защита, взлом

Можно ли защитить свой JavaScript код, от изменений через просмотра исходного кода через браузер. Допустим у меня есть веб-игра или веб-приложение написанный на JavaScript. Имея доступ к исходному коду хакер с легкостью может изменить мой код в пользу себе (результаты, достижения, очки, балы, монеты и т.д), да я сам так делал пару раз.

Можно ли защитить свой JavaScript код от таких атак?

Comment: нет, нельзя....

Comment: "результаты, достижения, очки, балы, монеты" - этим занимаются не хакеры, а школьники. Хакеры выполняют RCE)

Comment: - Обернуть код в функцию.
- Использовать замыкания

Comment: И то, и другое обходится при желании, защитит только от школьников :)

Comment: а как это происходит, результаты, очки, баллы. Это же все храниться в бд, допустим, при любой покупке, результаты берутся оттуда же и меняй не меняй js, толку не будет. Вопрос в другом можно ли поменять значения в бд используя ajax

Comment: от атак защитишься тогда, когда оффнешь сервер!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете пойти сразу двумя путями. 
Первый и простой, просто сделать uglify и минимизировать ваш исходный код. Это не особо подействует, но минимальных сложностей добавит.

Второе и единственное рабочее решение -  важную игровую логику должен контролировать сервер. Нужно перенести часть функционала на серверную часть.

Answer (score 2):

Никак, логику приложение должен обрабатывать [сервер](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5))

Answer (score 0):

Защита JavaScript кода от атак:

```
(function(w)
{
    //сюда вставляете ваш код
})(window);
```

Но это только полузащита. Хакер может переписывать обращения к серверу и его ответы, не используя браузер.

Comment: каким образом это может защитить код от атак?

Comment: @Grundy, от перезаписи кода